# Symfony 4 on heroku : log tails

Tags: heroku, symfony4

i try to deploy my app on heroku and i have this error :
[image]

I don't understand the documentation.
Can you help me please ?
Sorry for my english i'm french

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

1. Write how you deploy the app on the heroku (which commands you used).
2. Show the result of the heroku logs command.
3. Do u use webpack - if yes u should set up environment variables (NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION, YARN_PRODUCTION and NODE_MODULES_CACHE to false).
4. What do u have in Procfile file? For Symfony4 it should be look like this:

> web: $(composer config bin-dir)/heroku-php-apache2 public/

5. Did u run this command - it creating .htaccess file.

   > composer require apache-pack

Comment: 1 . i have deploy like on [documentation] (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-symfony) but it's seem to work with de version ^3.0 , it's work with your web: $(composer config bin-dir)/heroku-php-apache2 public/ . But if a want make other think like css , it's crash because the last command it's with symfony 4,2 .